# Chrome: Selected value in selectbox "flickers" when doing updates on cursor style

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, select

Just a small cosmetic problem, I've spent some hours to find out where the problem is and to create a jsfiddle on this issue (http://jsfiddle.net/josi/FUWBk/9/)

I've found out that if you do an update on the cursor style on a regular basis, the current marked value of an opened selectbox jumps back to it's defaultselected value.

Without this code:

```
document.body.style.cursor = 'progress';
```

and

```
document.body.style.cursor = '';
```

everything works fine.

Just open my jsfiddle and click on "Let's go". Move the opened popup away and open the select box and hover over some options and wait.

Does anybody has a workaround for this?

edit: No Problem in Firefox

Comment: I don't see any issue if I set the `progress` cursor. What OS are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 12.10, but this was seen on different os'es

Comment: I am starting to see this exact same issue in chrome, when you open a select list, the selected highlighting flickers up and down the list between the hovered and selected item...

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm still having it now.